# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript is not invoking the javascript function on ASPX page

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, telerik

Below is my code structure.

**ASPX:**

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            function finalConfirmationPopup(sliderWarningMsg) {
                 //Function definition
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {

            });

        </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
protected void OnOkayButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FinalConfirmationPopupOpener", "javascript:finalConfirmationPopup();", true);
}
```

But it fails to call the JS function finalConfirmationPopup().

Comment: I tried below but did not work.
string popupOpenerScript = "var popupPageurl = 'sample.aspx'; showModalDialog(popupPageurl, null, 'resizable:no;status:no;dialogWidth:500px;dialogHeight:500px;help:no;scroll:yes');";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FinalConfirmationPopupOpener", popupOpenerScript, true);

Comment: I did not try this yet.
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FinalConfirmationPopupOpener", "<script language=javascript>finalConfirmationPopup();</script>", true);